# All the Environment variables have been deleted in my Win7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I have overwritten all the paths in environment variables.
. How can i restore those variables back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the Windows 7 restore installation. It starts its run from within Windows 7.  I guess that should restore them.

You can try taking a fresh Windows 7 installation e.g. from a virtual machine, and copying the contents of the registry keys over, where the environment variables are stored.

win7

machine/system variables
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

user variables
`HKCU\Environment`

I notice one entry/variable called PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  and that may be different with a virtual machine. So trying a win7 restore is probably better than copying from a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet###\Control\Session Manager\Environment

\ControlSet\ being the one used, \ControlSet###\ being ones used to restore previous settings.

If they're the same, bad luck, then at best you can restore some. All the variables are program specific.

All you can do is make a PATH variable with some basic ones:
%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem

For java search for it, mine is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin

If you have ATI Catalyst, run a repair on the suit.

Temp variables are not picky, just make sure the locations are there.